# Beautifulsoup print attribute value for divs with same class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've got the following code working that will print the text after value=

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('input')['value']

print(name)
```

However the page has multiple divs with the same class I've tried findAll but I get errors and can only print the first field value which is the Name.

Please see the attached screen shot

[image: Browser Capture]

```html
<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label required" for="client_appbundle_prospecttype_ProspectFirstContact_decision_timeframe">What date do you want to make a decision?</label>
  <div class="controls"><input type="text" id="client_appbundle_prospecttype_ProspectFirstContact_decision_timeframe" name="client_appbundle_prospecttype[ProspectFirstContact][decision_timeframe]" required="required" class="input-small text-bound datepicker hasDatepicker"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="prospect_consultation">
  <div class="widget row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <h6>Personal details</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="controls">
            Sam Test-March 2018
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Address and postcode</label>
          <div class="controls">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Mobile number</label>
          <div class="controls">
            12345678
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
          <div class="controls">
            test@test.com
          </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to include HTML, not as an image. Also, your shown HTML does not have input tag elements visible.

Comment: I've uploaded the code to the snippet view now.

Comment: what are you trying to extract from that snippet?

Comment: Hi QHarr, I'm trying to get the values in the fields under Name, Address and postcode, Mobile number etc the page has many of these fields with different labels so I'm trying a find_all which produces errors, yet when I run the find code It will just print the first label only which is the Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label required" for="client_appbundle_prospecttype_ProspectFirstContact_decision_timeframe">What date do you want to make a decision?</label>
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="client_appbundle_prospecttype_ProspectFirstContact_decision_timeframe" name="client_appbundle_prospecttype[ProspectFirstContact][decision_timeframe]" required class="input-small text-bound datepicker hasDatepicker">
   </div>
  </div>     
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="prospect_consultation"> 
   <div class="widget row-fluid"> 
    <div class="span12"> 
     <div class="navbar"> 
      <div class="navbar-inner"> 
       <h6>Personal details</h6> 
      </div> 
     </div> 
     <div class="well"> 
      <div class="control-group"> 
       <label class="control-label">Name</label> 
       <div class="controls">
         Sam Test-March 2018 
       </div> 
      </div> 
      <div class="control-group"> 
       <label class="control-label">Address and postcode</label> 
       <div class="controls"> 
       </div> 
      </div> 
      <div class="control-group"> 
       <label class="control-label">Mobile number</label> 
       <div class="controls">
         12345678 
       </div> 
      </div> 
      <div class="control-group"> 
       <label class="control-label">Email address</label> 
       <div class="controls">
         test@test.com 
       </div> 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

items = soup.select('.controls')
print([item.text.strip() for item in items if item.text.strip()])
```

Comment: Thanks!

Could I specify particular fields, so something like only strip the value for 'Address and postcode' & 'Name' etc

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If html has constant layout you could use position matching to perform this or xpath that looks for specific strings.